# Trying to use Cuda in pyTorch

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch

I've been working on PyTorch and wanted to use Cuda tensors but I've been having trouble getting it to work.

When I use the line torch.cuda.is_available(), it returns false.

But when I use the same line on the anaconda command prompt, it returns true. What gives? Do I need to set the device somehow? Or maybe have the interpreter include my GPU? All I want is my GPU to be recognized as CUDA usable and can use in code.

I use:

python 3.7

CUDA 10.1

GPU: GTX 1070

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, My interpreter was wrong and I changed it to match my anaconda prompt interpreter. Works like a charm